# What is the right way to write Sass functions?

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, webpack, angular-cli

I am working on Angular 2 using Webpack. I created my SCSS file in my component and put below code inside it but SCSS mixins not working and other CSS is still working properly, also if I create variables they also work properly and no error showing on `angular-cli` while building my code. Here is my code:

```
@mixin widthbypercentage($from-number, $to-number) {
    /* Firefox */
    width: -moz-calc($from-number - $to-number);
    /* WebKit */
    width: -webkit-calc($from-number - $to-number);
    /* Opera */
    width: -o-calc($from-number - $to-number);
    /* Standard */
    width: calc($from-number - $to-number);
}

@mixin heightbypercentage($from-number, $to-number) {
    /* Firefox */
    height: -moz-calc($from-number - $to-number);
    /* WebKit */
    height: -webkit-calc($from-number - $to-number);
    /* Opera */
    height: -o-calc($from-number - $to-number);
    /* Standard */
    height: calc($from-number - $to-number);
}

.ah-categories-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    @include widthbypercentage(100%, 40%);
    @include heightbypercentage(100%, 130px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

I also visit [this](http://thesassway.com/advanced/pure-sass-functions) link and copy and run mentioned functions all of them is working perfectly. I thought there might be something wrong in my code.

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at this github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/678

Comment: Other sass variables are working... only above mixins not working.

Comment: Rather than using Sass functions at all here, use autoprefixer. That way you won't need to add browser prefixes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using variables for CSS `calc()`, put them inside this `#{ }`:

```
@mixin widthbypercentage($from-number, $to-number) {
    /* Firefox */
    width: -moz-calc(#{$from-number} - #{$to-number});
    /* WebKit */
    width: -webkit-calc(#{$from-number} - #{$to-number});
    /* Opera */
    width: -o-calc(#{$from-number} - #{$to-number});
    /* Standard */
    width: calc(#{$from-number} - #{$to-number});
}

@mixin heightbypercentage($from-number, $to-number) {
    /* Firefox */
    height: -moz-calc(#{$from-number} - #{$to-number});
    /* WebKit */
    height: -webkit-calc(#{$from-number} - #{$to-number});
    /* Opera */
    height: -o-calc(#{$from-number} - #{$to-number});
    /* Standard */
    height: calc(#{$from-number} - #{$to-number});
}

.ah-categories-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    @include widthbypercentage(100%, 40%);
    @include heightbypercentage(100%, 130px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

---

CSS3 `calc()` is now [fully supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), therefore no need for browser prefixes.